# JMeter - Result configuration pass vs fail

Tags: configuration, jmeter

I have a JMeter testplan which has 2 simple data writer listeners called passed and failed. I would like to use them in such a way that all successful responses should goto passed and all failed responses should go to failed. So I checked Log/Display only errors to failed and Successes to passed. I also clicked configure button to check save success on passed and unchecked the same for failed listener.  Are there any other specific options do i have select/deselect in this result save configuration option that are related to passed/failed responses?.

Comment: Did you get a working answer for this?

Comment: Gaff, I have proceeded with whatever I had along with your recommendations. So we can call your answer as a working answer :-).

Answer (score 0):

You have the major ones listed, and the log/display option configured correctly.

For the "Failed" listener, I would also check "Save Assertion Failure Message" (top of the 3rd column in ver 2.4) and possible "Save Sample and Error Counts" if you're interested (bottom of the 3rd column).